# XML to c# unable to convert

Tags: c#, xml

> ```
> <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?> <DPDocument>   <TradingPartnerDirectory>
> <Sender>
>   <TradingPartner ParticipantType="Distributor">
>     <CompanyID>200408144</CompanyID>
>     <CompanyName>Union Gas Ltd</CompanyName>
>   </TradingPartner>
> </Sender>
> <Recipient>
>   <TradingPartner ParticipantType="Retailer">
>     <CompanyID>DUNS24653</CompanyID>
>     <CompanyName>Local Authority Services Limited</CompanyName>
>   </TradingPartner>
> </Recipient>   </TradingPartnerDirectory>   <ContractInformation>
> <ContractID>SA1854</ContractID>
> <ContractName>GASAMO #1 EDA-ABC</ContractName>
> <Amendment>24</Amendment>
> <FirstDeliveryDate>11/1/2011</FirstDeliveryDate>
> <EffectiveDate>11/1/2011</EffectiveDate>
> <DeliveryArea>EDA</DeliveryArea>
> <TotalDCQ>546</TotalDCQ>
> <EnergyFactor>37.51</EnergyFactor>
> <EndUseLocationInformation>
>   <AccountNumber>10109251120297</AccountNumber>
>   <AccountName>TOWN OF DESERONTO</AccountName>
>   <RateClass>01</RateClass>
>   <ServiceClass>C</ServiceClass>
>   <ForecastInformation>
>     <BillingMonth>JAN</BillingMonth>
>     <BillingYear>2011</BillingYear>
>     <Consumption>1116.0040</Consumption>
>     <WeatherFactor>1.045723</WeatherFactor>
>   </ForecastInformation>
>   <ForecastInformation>
>     <BillingMonth>FEB</BillingMonth>
>     <BillingYear>2011</BillingYear>
>     <Consumption>1269.7390</Consumption>
>     <WeatherFactor>0.937073</WeatherFactor>
>   </ForecastInformation>
>   <ForecastInformation>
>     <BillingMonth>MAR</BillingMonth>
>     <BillingYear>2011</BillingYear>
>     <Consumption>2064.0370</Consumption>
>     <WeatherFactor>1.015836</WeatherFactor>
>   </ForecastInformation>
>   <ForecastInformation>
>     <BillingMonth>APR</BillingMonth>
>     <BillingYear>2011</BillingYear>
>     <Consumption>82.5610</Consumption>
>     <WeatherFactor>0.982911</WeatherFactor>
>   </ForecastInformation>
>   <ForecastInformation>
>     <BillingMonth>MAY</BillingMonth>
>     <BillingYear>2011</BillingYear>
>     <Consumption>546.6140</Consumption>
>     <WeatherFactor>0.972752</WeatherFactor>
>   </ForecastInformation>
>   <ForecastInformation>
>     <BillingMonth>JUN</BillingMonth>
>     <BillingYear>2011</BillingYear>
>     <Consumption>128.1130</Consumption>
>     <WeatherFactor>1</WeatherFactor>
>   </ForecastInformation>
>   <ForecastInformation>
>     <BillingMonth>JUL</BillingMonth>
>     <BillingYear>2011</BillingYear>
>     <Consumption>5.6940</Consumption>
>     <WeatherFactor>1</WeatherFactor>
>   </ForecastInformation>
>   <ForecastInformation>
>     <BillingMonth>AUG</BillingMonth>
>     <BillingYear>2011</BillingYear>
>     <Consumption>0</Consumption>
>     <WeatherFactor>1</WeatherFactor>
>   </ForecastInformation>
>   <ForecastInformation>
>     <BillingMonth>SEP</BillingMonth>
>     <BillingYear>2010</BillingYear>
>     <Consumption>0</Consumption>
>     <WeatherFactor>1</WeatherFactor>
>   </ForecastInformation>
>   <ForecastInformation>
>     <BillingMonth>OCT</BillingMonth>
>     <BillingYear>2010</BillingYear>
>     <Consumption>2.8470</Consumption>
>     <WeatherFactor>0.993534</WeatherFactor>
>   </ForecastInformation>
>   <ForecastInformation>
>     <BillingMonth>NOV</BillingMonth>
>     <BillingYear>2010</BillingYear>
>     <Consumption>290.3890</Consumption>
>     <WeatherFactor>1.0585</WeatherFactor>
>   </ForecastInformation>
>   <ForecastInformation>
>     <BillingMonth>DEC</BillingMonth>
>     <BillingYear>2010</BillingYear>
>     <Consumption>686.1140</Consumption>
>     <WeatherFactor>0.938379</WeatherFactor>
>   </ForecastInformation>
> </EndUseLocationInformation>
> <EndUseLocationInformation>
>   <AccountNumber>10110651120442</AccountNumber>
>   <AccountName>COMMUNITY CENTRE</AccountName>
>   <RateClass>01</RateClass>
>   <ServiceClass>C</ServiceClass>
>   <ForecastInformation>
>     <BillingMonth>JAN</BillingMonth>
>     <BillingYear>2011</BillingYear>
>     <Consumption>4327.3610</Consumption>
>     <WeatherFactor>1.045723</WeatherFactor>
>   </ForecastInformation>
>   <ForecastInformation>
>     <BillingMonth>FEB</BillingMonth>
>     <BillingYear>2011</BillingYear>
>     <Consumption>4811.3420</Consumption>
>     <WeatherFactor>0.937073</WeatherFactor>
>   </ForecastInformation>
>   <ForecastInformation>
>     <BillingMonth>MAR</BillingMonth>
>     <BillingYear>2011</BillingYear>
>     <Consumption>5924.4990</Consumption>
>     <WeatherFactor>1.015836</WeatherFactor>
>   </ForecastInformation>
>   <ForecastInformation>
>     <BillingMonth>APR</BillingMonth>
>     <BillingYear>2011</BillingYear>
>     <Consumption>4971.9730</Consumption>
>     <WeatherFactor>0.982911</WeatherFactor>
>   </ForecastInformation>
>   <ForecastInformation>
>     <BillingMonth>MAY</BillingMonth>
>     <BillingYear>2011</BillingYear>
>     <Consumption>2302.5290</Consumption>
>     <WeatherFactor>0.972752</WeatherFactor>
>   </ForecastInformation>
>   <ForecastInformation>
>     <BillingMonth>JUN</BillingMonth>
>     <BillingYear>2011</BillingYear>
>     <Consumption>761.1410</Consumption>
>     <WeatherFactor>1</WeatherFactor>
>   </ForecastInformation>
>   <ForecastInformation>
>     <BillingMonth>JUL</BillingMonth>
>     <BillingYear>2011</BillingYear>
>     <Consumption>350.3160</Consumption>
>     <WeatherFactor>1</WeatherFactor>
>   </ForecastInformation>
>   <ForecastInformation>
>     <BillingMonth>AUG</BillingMonth>
>     <BillingYear>2011</BillingYear>
>     <Consumption>267.5140</Consumption>
>     <WeatherFactor>1</WeatherFactor>
>   </ForecastInformation>
>   <ForecastInformation>
>     <BillingMonth>SEP</BillingMonth>
>     <BillingYear>2010</BillingYear>
>     <Consumption>42.7050</Consumption>
>     <WeatherFactor>1</WeatherFactor>
>   </ForecastInformation>
>   <ForecastInformation>
>     <BillingMonth>OCT</BillingMonth>
>     <BillingYear>2010</BillingYear>
>     <Consumption>416.8490</Consumption>
>     <WeatherFactor>0.993534</WeatherFactor>
>     <WeatherFactor>0.993534</WeatherFactor>
>   </ForecastInformation>
>   <ForecastInformation>
>     <BillingMonth>NOV</BillingMonth>
>     <BillingYear>2010</BillingYear>
>     <Consumption>1389.3110</Consumption>
>     <WeatherFactor>1.0585</WeatherFactor>
>   </ForecastInformation>
>   <ForecastInformation>
>     <BillingMonth>DEC</BillingMonth>
>     <BillingYear>2010</BillingYear>
>     <Consumption>1641.4940</Consumption>
>     <WeatherFactor>0.938379</WeatherFactor>
>   </ForecastInformation>
> </EndUseLocationInformation>  </DPDocument>
> ```

above is the my xml code.. i am unable to convert that into c# class below is the c# class which i created for that xml

```
public class DPDocument
{
    public TradingPartnerDirectory tradingpartnerdirectory
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public ContractInformation contractInformation
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public DPDocument()
    {
        tradingpartnerdirectory = new TradingPartnerDirectory();
        contractInformation = new ContractInformation();
    }
}

public class TradingPartnerDirectory
{
    public Sender sender
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public Recipient recipient
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public TradingPartnerDirectory()
    {
        sender = new Sender();
        recipient = new Recipient();
    }
}

public class Sender
{
    public TradingPartner tradingPartner
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public Sender()
    {
        tradingPartner = new TradingPartner();
    }
}

public class Recipient
{
    public TradingPartner tradingPartner
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public Recipient()
    {
        tradingPartner = new TradingPartner();
    }
}

public class TradingPartner
{
    [XmlAttribute("ParticipantType")]
    public string ParticipantType
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public long CompanyID
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public string CompanyName
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}

public class ContractInformation
{
    public string ContractID
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public string ContractName
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public int Amendment
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public DateTime FirstDeliveryDate
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public DateTime EffectiveDate
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public string DeliveryArea
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public int TotalDCQ
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public decimal EnergyFactor
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public List<EndUseLocationInformation> child
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public ContractInformation()
    {
        child = new List<EndUseLocationInformation>();
    }
}

public class EndUseLocationInformation
{
    public long AccountNumber
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public string AccountName
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public int RateClass
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public string ServiceClass
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public List<ForecastInformation> childchild
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public EndUseLocationInformation()
    {
        childchild = new List<ForecastInformation>();
    }
}

public class ForecastInformation
{
    public string BillingMonth
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public int BillingYear
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
    public decimal Consumption
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public decimal WeatherFactor
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public ForecastInformation()
    {

    }
}
```

i am not able to convert that into c# DPDocument object in one single shot,i tried in all ways but i am not achieve that one. 
at last i went to a worst solution like by taking individual node list and process that list finally that approach worked for me. but i need an elegant solution to resolve my prob. 
Thank you in advance :)

Answer (score 2):

When you have a valid XML document, you can do a two-step process:

1. run the `xsd.exe` command line tool that gets installed with the .NET framework to convert your XML into a XSD (XML schema):

   ```
   c:\> xsd.exe yourfile.xml
   ```

   This will create a file called `yourfile.xsd` in the same location which you'll need for the second step.
2. run the `xsd.exe` command line tool again, converting your XML schema into C# code:

   ```
   c:\> xsd.exe /c yourfile.xsd
   ```

   This will create a file called `yourfile.cs` in the same location that contains the C# classes and helper structures that you need to deserialize this particular XML you're dealing with.

Now, with that C# file, you should be able to do:

```
XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(DPDocument));
TextReader tr = new StreamReader(@"path-to-your-XML-file-here"); 
var result = serializer.Deserialize(tr);
```

and you should get your `DPDocument` class deserialized from your XML file.

In this concrete case, when trying to do this, you'll stumble over an error - this is because the `XSD` tool does a good - but not perfect - job based on your XML input file. You need to fix this manually:

```
public partial class DPDocumentTradingPartnerDirectory {
  private TradingPartner[][] senderField;
  private TradingPartner[][] recipientField;
```

XSD inferred from the XML that you might have an array of arrays here. I assume in reality, you don't actually have this (I don't know that particular XML - that's just my assumption) - and if that's the case, then you only have "one level" of arrays, so you need to correct this manually to be:

```
public partial class DPDocumentTradingPartnerDirectory {
  private TradingPartner[] senderField;
  private TradingPartner[] recipientField;
```

But once you've done this - deserialization works flawlessly and you've converted your XML file into C# in hardly any time at all!

Comment: Why not go straight from XML to C#? (actually, I can think of some answers for this, but I was curious what your thinking was)

Comment: i tried TextReader tr = null;       
        XmlSerializer serializer2 = null;
        DPDocument dpDocument = null;
        serializer2 = new XmlSerializer(typeof(DPDocument), "DPDocument");
        tr = new StreamReader(@"E:\Consumption_Forecast_SA1854_24 - Copy.xml");
        dpDocument = (DPDocument)serializer2.Deserialize(tr);                             but i am not able to convert.

Comment: @sq33G: how?? The XSD tool works on XML->XSD and XSD->CS, I don't think you can go from XML directly to C#. And doing all of this manually is a bit of a messy and time-consuming affair....

Comment: @Ramakrishna: well - what happens? Do you get an error - if so: **WHAT** error?

Comment: eh, my bad. Read the doc at [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x6c1kb0s(v=vs.71).aspx) more carefully.

Answer (score 1):

Try that: NOT VALID XML ;) Check start and end and you see that not all tags get closed.

Comment: Not the only one ;) Actually there is more. There is thus NO way to deal with this document through standard XML mechanisms.

Comment: if u find any tags are not closed, sorry for that its my mistake but my xml file look like that only and it well in format. if u have any idea to convert that one plz give ur valuable solution to me thank you :)